# 2004 Honda Civic, No Start, No Power, Key Light Previous Trip, Possible Spark Plug?

Tags: honda, civic

On the last trip I made my car (Honda Civic 2004 Sedan VP) had trouble starting. It clicked as if it had trouble getting power but eventually started up although the key light was on.

I drove home as it was late at night. Now when I put key in ignition and turn nothing happens at all. No lights, no power, nothing.

A mechanic mentioned when I was getting new tires that my spark plugs were going to need to be changed soon. I have also recently replaced battery a month ago.

I am wondering if bad spark plugs could be the reason for this and would replacing them solve the issue? Also with the keylight turning on previously does this mean that my key needs to be reprogrammed at the dealership. I was able to drive with the light on previously and also have an additional key I have not tried.

Comment: You might need a new mechanic. Replacing the spark plugs when there is no power sounds fishy. I'd check the ignition key switch.

Comment: That was a comment made at the place that replaced my tires not my regular mechanic. I figured I would have it checked at my upcoming maintenance.

Comment: Im pretty sure it is linked to the battery connection since it started to be intermittent on your last trip. Check the connection, there is probably some corrosion that you can simply clean and it'll work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark plugs will certainly not be causing this problem. Check the battery connections.

Some garages will carry out battery checks for free, so this is an easy way of getting the connections checked.

Comment: You should elaborate on exactly what the OP should be checking WRT the battery connection. Be specific. I agree with what you said, just realize most people when they ask questions like this don't know exactly what your expecting with your answer or they wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @paulster - thanks for the advice.  I do think it can be dangerous encouraging people to do something that they don't understand.  If they don't know how to check connections on the battery, they would be best asking someone to check them for them.

Comment: I would also suggest going to a garage. They often do battery checks for free, so they would (hopefully!) tighten the connections. I've edited this in

Comment: @HandyHowie - Just because someone isn't knowledgeable does not mean they aren't *capable*. Let them decide what they can do. People come to a site like this expecting complete answers. People don't come to this site wanting to see "*take it to a mechanic*".

Comment: I'd love to take it to a mechanic as is my intention, but I'd like to avoid having it towed there if possible. I will check battery connections when the rain stops. I'm assuming you mean checking connections for corrosion and tightness.

Comment: Yes, make sure you don't short them out with your spanner.

Comment: Connections are good.. still no crank, no start

Comment: I took them off and steel brushed them retightened just to be sure

Comment: Did you say that your lights are not working either, are all circuits dead?  Are you able to see if the battery had any power in it at all by connecting a 12v bulb to it?

Comment: Lights aren't working. Unfortunately I don't have what's needed for 12v bulb test. If lights aren't working at all is possible that a jump start might work.

Comment: You could try putting jump leads on.  Unless you have got jump leads with very thick wire, then you will need to leave the jump leads connected for a few minutes so that the battery charges up a little before you try to start the car.  With the symptoms you described of clicking when trying to start the car and it then starting OK, it still sounds like a bad connection somewhere.  Just to clarify, when I asked about the lights, I meant the headlights.  Is there anything electrical working e.g. the interior light, horn, radio?

Comment: I was able to jump the car with cables. It's at the mechanic now, so will update when I know more.

Comment: It ended up being that there was a problem with the breaks that made the brake lights stay on and thus drained the battery.

Comment: Please to hear that your problem is solved.